# Confusing Notation

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I have problem with notation in some article (I got only some part of it, don't know whole paper and hence can't find in "Notations").

"Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ a subspace which is a dual: $Y=Z^*$. Let $V$ be a subset of $X^*$ such that $V \ | \ Y \subset QZ$, where $Q$ is defined as the cannonical embedding of $Z$ into $Z^{**}$."

What does mean: ${V \ | \ Y}  \subset QZ \ \ $ (I mean the straigh line)?

Answer (score 3):

The vertical bar means restriction, and in this case it is applied on a set of linear functionals, so $V \mid Y = \{f\mid Y: f ∈ V\}$, which is a subset of $Y^* = Z^{**}$. Clearly, $QZ$ is also a subset of $Z^{**}$, so the expression $V \mid Y ⊂ QZ$ means $(V \mid Y) ⊂ QZ$.